# Why SDL of GraphQL generated by nestjs, makes nullable field to be required?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I am developing using the code first approach
The schema generate by nestjs ignores the nullable: true for another object type

```
// user.entity.ts
@ObjectType()
export class UserObjectType implements User {
  @Field()
  id: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true})
  name: string;

 @Field(type => UserServicesObjectType, { 
    nullable: true, //  here i declare as nullable
 })
  services: UserServicesObjectType | null;
}
```

```
// schema.gql (autogenerated)
type UserObjectType {
  id: String!
  name: String
services: UserServicesObjectType! //  but the schema is generated as no-null
}
```

## I expected it to be

```
// schema.gql (autogenerated)
type UserObjectType {
  id: String!
  name: String
services: UserServicesObjectType //  I expected to be nullable (without the !)
}
```